# How to get a notification when the device name of an iOS device changes?

Tags: ios, swift

iOS devices have a 'name', that the user can set in Settings > General > About > Name. For example, something like "Bob's iPhone". In Swift, you can obtain this name by using

```swift
UIDevice.current.name
```

However, I would like to respond in my app in the (rare) case that the user changes this name in Settings. I already looked at `NSNotification.Name` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name), but I could not find what I'm looking for. Also the information about [UIDevice](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice) contained nothing helpful.

Does anybody have an idea about this?

Comment: In the UIDevice documentation page, Notifications does not list any notifications that would be triggered when the device name changes, generally if it isn't documented on Apple's documentation you either cannot do it... or shouldn't (using private API's will normally get your app rejected during review)

Comment: I imagine that fetching the device name isn't a very expensive operation. You could simply get the name every time your app enters the foreground; the device name cannot change while your app is in the foreground. You can save the device name in UserDefaults and simply compare the saved and current name to determine if there has been a name change.

Comment: @Scriptable Yeah, I know. I thought, maybe I missed something, but probably that's not the case.

Comment: @Paulw11 That's a nice solution! Clever idea. I think I will use that, unless another solution will be found.